# PHP File upload: file too large, while it is not

Tags: php

I've been pulling hairs on this one. I am creating a quit simple file upload application. On a specific point, the files are not uploaded and I receive the message: "Sorry, your file is too large.". I am uploading a file of ±2MB.

The relevant parameters in the php.ini are:

```
file_uploads        On
max_execution_time  60
max_file_uploads    20
post_max_size       32M
upload_max_filesize 32M
```

So, there shouldn't be a problem there. Anybody an idea?

Used code:

```
if (isset($_POST['fileUploadBtn'])) {
        echo 'File Size: '.$_FILES['file']['size'];
        if(isset($_FILES['file']['error'])) {
            echo $error_types[$_FILES['file']['error']].'<br>'; 
        }

        if(isset($_FILES["file"])) {
            if($_FILES["file"]["name"] != '') {
                uploadFile($mysqli, $orderid, $md5, $_FILES["file"], 'weefontwerp');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which code do you use for the upload?

Comment: No idea without seeing the code..

Comment: Have you restarted your server after changing these values?

Comment: I have not changed the values in php.ini. These were default. The code I'm using is now set in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, did you check the file size?
like this:

```
if ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] > 500000) {
    echo 'file too large.';
}
```

Or, did you restart php to reload the php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem was in the downloaded upload function. There was the check, I forgot to check. I'm terribly sorry to post this here!